# jQuery stop function running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using slideUp / down to show and hide content and have written it to that it will close any visible content when opening another one.  This works until I try to close content by clicking on it, it opens it again straight away.

The HTML

```
<ul class="contents">
   <li>
      while($results->fetch()){
          <div class="details">text</div>
          <div class="more_details">more text</div>
      }
   </li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery

```
$("#results").on("click", ".details", function() {
    $(".open").slideUp(600, function() {
        $(".open").css("display", "none").removeClass("open");
    });

    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
        $(this).slideUp( 600, function() {
            $(this).css("display", "none").removeClass("open");
        });
    } else {
        $(this).next(".more_details").slideDown(600, function() {
            $(this).css("display", "show").addClass("open");
        });
    }   
});
```

Comment: can you share the html sample also

Comment: your open and close are not symmetric. You are closing the `details`, but opening `more_details`

Comment: @gurvinder372 the OP's code is correct - although it was hard to see due to it's layout. I've fixed the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the slide down code you are working with the next sibling `more_details`, where in the slide up code you are dealing with `this` element.

```js
$("#results").on("click", ".details", function() {
  var $details = $(this).next(".more_details");
  $details.slideToggle(600, function() {
    $details.toggleClass("open");
  });
  $(".more_details.open").not($details).slideUp(600, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">
  <div class="details">details</div>
  <div class="more_details">more_details</div>
  <div class="details">details</div>
  <div class="more_details">more_details</div>
  <div class="details">details</div>
  <div class="more_details">more_details</div>
  <div class="details">details</div>
  <div class="more_details">more_details</div>
</div>
```